# How to check for duplicate values in a Case When Statement

Tags: oracle, duplicates, case-when

I am trying to check for duplicate values as one of several checks in a case when statement. I am using SQL Developer and Oracle version 11.2 and SQL Developer Version 17.2

The first part of the code looking for duplicate ID is where I am stuck, I am trying to check if column ID from TABLE_RECORDS has duplicate values.

I then run additional QC check in the rest of the statement 
(This is a segment of a much longer CASE WHEN statement just for reference)

I can't tell if it is a syntax issue or if there is a better way to solve the issue.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (
SELECT r.ID, COUNT(r.ID)
    FROM r
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT (ID) > 1) 'Duplicate ID'
  WHEN r.ID IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
ELSE 'pass'
END AS Check_ID

    CASE WHEN r.First IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
ELSE 'pass'
     END AS Check_First_Name
from TABLE_RECORDS r
```

Comment: You can't be using Oracle version 17.2, the current version is 12.2. Run `select * from v$version` to find out your version; 17.2 is probably your SQL Developer version. SQL Developer is a separate piece of software; you use it to interact with the database, but it is not part of the Oracle Database.

Comment: Hi, you're right, I'm running Oracle 11.2 and SQL Developer 17.2 thanks for catching that, I've edited the original question.

Comment: Does the query not return the correct results or is there an another problem here?

Comment: If you don't want to allow duplicates, why wouldn't you rather create a unique index on that column (ID in your example)?

Comment: Dolos's answer below worked for me, the above query errors out "missing expression". As for duplicates this is actually a report to flag potential errors for a client rather than actually changing any data at this point. Thank you all.

Comment: Refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546430/create-a-flag-value-based-on-the-duplicate-values-on-one-column-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

If table_records is relatively small, why not try a left outer join instead:

```
select  case 
          when a2.id is not null 
            then 'Duplicate ID'
            else null
        end check_id,
        case
          when a1.first is not null
            then 'Pass'
            else null
        end check_first_name
from    table_records a1
left outer join
        (
        select  id
        from    table_records
        group by id
        having count(*) > 1
        ) a2 on a1.id = a2.id;
```

Makes it a bit easier to read and simplifies the case when statements.  Also it's rarely advisable to convert null into a string ('NULL'), usually best to leave it as null.

Comment: Brilliant, this works perfectly, I completely forgot about joining the temporary tables. Also thanks for the 'NULL' advice, in this case the 'NULL' is a flag for a client rather than actually converting the value. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!  And if 'NULL' is a flag then I really would suggest using a different word or phrase such as 'Unique ID' and 'Fail' for your case when statements instead.  Makes it clearer for the client and you won't run into issues down the line.