# Create a flag value based on the duplicate values on one column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, dense-rank

I am quite new to SQL. Playing around with it and got stuck in the following scenario.

I have a table with the following data

[image]

My requirement is, in the FirstCol column, it has '11121' 3 times, and SecondCol has 1001 two times against FirstCol and it has 1002 against the same '11121' value which should not be. If it exists that way, I need to find all the data in such scenarios and need to display a column beside these two columns with a flag value indicating 1 if the value in the SecondCol is different than the other values. '0' should be displayed for the remaining.

I tried using group by, dense_rank() but couldn't get the desired results. Someone please help me out in getting the desired result for this.

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Comment: Your description makes no sense.  I see `11121` *2* times, not *3*.  After that, I'm lost.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(col1) over (partition by col2) =
                  max(col1) over (partition by col2)
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

This flags all rows where `col2` has multiple values in `col1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery, that checks, if there are row with the same `firstcol` but with a different `secondcol`. Put that in a `CASE` returning `1` if such a record exists, `0` otherwise.

```
SELECT t1.firstcol,
       t1.secondcol,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM elbat t2
                             WHERE t2.firstcol = t1.firstcol
                                   AND t2.secondcol <> t1.secondcol) THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END flag
       FROM elbat t1;
```